Signal processing; block structure. Finding the transfer function to the system


The implementation scheme for a causal LTI digital system with one
input, x[n], and one output, y[n] is shown in Figure P3. In the
figure, z−1 represents a unit sample delay and α is a scalar constant.
From the frequency response characteristics, H( f ), of the system,
determine whether it is a low-pass, high-pass, band-pass, band-stop,
or all-pass filter.

I have sat up the two equations below. I dont know if the two equations are true:
L1 := Y(z) = V(z) + (-X(z) + V(z)/z);
L2 := V(z) = V(z)/z + a*(X(z) - V(z)/z);

Post your question here.
